# Задача python. Помогите!

Tags: python, функции, математика

Ломаю голову третий день над задачей. Есть функция `func(x,y,z)` внутри которой зашиты константы `a, b, c` (натуральные числа). Функция возвращает `a*x + b*y + c*z`. Нужно получить `a**2 + b**2 + c**2` за 2 вызова функции** (x, y, z - целочисленные значения). **Больше двух раз функцию вызывать нельзя!!**

Comment: Не пробовали первое выражение в квадрат возвести?

Comment: Ну будет квадрат суммы. А ответом на задачу является сумма квадратов

Comment: Може быть , вид этого квадрата наведёт на какие-нибудь мысли по комбинированию выражений и значений переменных

Comment: я уже этот квадрат как не крутил только. Понятно, что сумма квадратов = (a+b+c)^2  - 2ab - 2ac - 2cb. Уже всю тетрадь исписал))) Буду рад подсказке чуточку пожирнее

Comment: Увы, у меня тоже не получилось. Рассчитывал, что комбинации переменных типа (1,1,-1) помогут, но не вышло.

Comment: возможно есть хитрость какая то? я уже думал сделать копию функции или каким то образом получить доступ к переменным. Просто ступор

Comment: Наверное, есть хитрость. Для двух подходов - тройки аргументов (x,y,z) и (t,u,x) линейная комбинация квадратов результатов - [решений нет](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve++x%5E2-t%5E2%3D1%2C+y%5E2-u%5E2%3D1%2C+z%5E2-v%5E2%3D1%2C+x*y-t*u%3D0%2C+x*z-t*v%3D0%2C+y*z-u*v%3D0), и произведение результатов (как скалярное произведение) - вроде тоже [решений нет](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+complex%3A+x*t%3D1%2C+y*u%3D1%2C+z*v%3D1%2C+x*u%2By*t%3D0%2C+x*v%2Bz*t%3D0%2C+y*v%2Bz*u%3D0)